# IPC-Bridge problem

Tags: mobile-robot, software, slam, ros

Is anyone able to help me out getting IPC-bridge working on my ubuntu lucid installation (with matlab 2012a)? I'm not being able to finish the last step on here (Compiling the messages folders): https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge#Installation

I'm able to rosmake the ipc_bridge_ros, however when i enter this "roscd ipc_roslib && make", it seems meX does not recognize the commands. Here is what i get (screen shot): http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/6031/screenshot20121108at191.png

NOTE: i'm going to use IPC-bridge so that i can control a pioneer 3DX and implement a Fast-slam algorithm in matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That script is calling "mex" but it's getting pdfTex "mex" tool instead of the Matlab compiler.

Before running that script you need to adjust your `PATH` environment variable to put the Matlab binaries before your system ones.  Assuming your Matlab binaries are located in `/opt/matlab/bin` that would look something like this:

```
export PATH=/opt/matlab/bin:$PATH
roscd ipc_roslib && make
```